# Trying to install WSL / Ubuntu on my machine but getting a difficult error

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting this error: and have tried majority of the solution online to no avail.

````
Ubuntu is already installed.
Launching Ubuntu...
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070050
Error: 0x80070050 The file exists.```

I hope someone can help me with this error, upon further research it feels like it's a windows error more than a linux error? But I can't seem to solve it

I have tried the following:
- Turning on Windows features: WSL and Hyper-V
- Using sfc and DISM
- Restarting LXSS Manager
- CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows

and many more
````